# Is it bad practice to instantiate a Form from a UserControl?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I am building an application using the .NET CF Framework and I had a situation where I wanted to present the user with a custom Dialog Box.

My solution was to create a simple Form with radio buttons for choices and a button.  When clicked the button saves the selected radio button value to a public property and closes the Form.

The UserControl, after calling ShowDialog on the Form, inspects the public property to learn what option the user picked.

This worked perfectly.  I'm just wondering if this is bad practice and if i'm going to get myself in trouble, somehow by doing this.  It seems odd that a UserControl should be creating a Form.

Is there a better way to go about creating a custom Dialog Box from within a UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely nothing wrong with that.  It is essentially the same as calling `MessageBox.Show()` from a UserControl.

And yes, accessing the result as a public property is the way to do it.

I'm guessing that this will be a dialog?  You should consider using the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) if you have multiple 'exit' options - OK, Cancel, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I've been off experimenting with using the DialogResult to return different results.  Not necessary in what i'm doing.  I just have the single button to Close() the form after a selection has been made.  But it is good to know that if I wanted I could have multiple buttons and return a different DialogResult if I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it shouldn't give you any problems.

Long answer: As your application grows, doing things like opening a Form directly from a UserControl might give you some spaghetti-like code. If you write an application larger than a few thousands lines of code, your Form and UserControl code behind files should typically be quite empty. They should not contain any business logic, and preferably not any UI logic either. Look at patterns such as [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) how to achieve this.